# How can I dynamically change keyframe values from code in Unity 5?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have gameObject with animator attached to it, it has animation curves, I need to dynamically change keyframe values from code. How do I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already asked this in the Live Session. The Answer is you can't since the anim file is the core for running the Animation Controller.

The alternate way that they gave me is to use the legacy SpriteRenderer instead.

Animation Controller doesn't support Dynamic changing of the values. Instead they provided Animator for you to make Dynamic changes of path from anim files, so consider making different anim files and path to your Animator if you don't like to work with SpriteRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

If "dynamically" still means **editor-time**, then you could use [UnityEditor.AnimationUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.html), which provides methods to get and set curves and key frames and more.

One can retrieve the bindings with AnimationUtility.GetCurveBindings() or AnimationUtility.GetObjectReferenceCurveBindings(). And with AnimationUtility.GetObjectReferenceCurve() one can get the key frames, make modifications and apply it with AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve()

At **runtime** - probably only with workarounds.

For example via some animated relay value within a certain custom script that then applies the wanted value to the actual property on Update() - a kind of custom constraint if you will. And within that you could apply then again custom modifications via code on runtime. But on editor time and when animating, the preview would be broken because you would not directly animate the property, but only that relay value. Maybe one could use [ExecuteInEditMode] in that custom constraint behaviour and AnimationMode.InAnimationMode() to simulate a preview. But all of this would be experimental.